# Generate Customise Report With MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, transactions

I am designing a website that needs to generate a report. The report has to generate the detail transactions and the total transactions grouped by days transactions  were done.The data table format is presented below.

```html
 _______________________________________

    |Name | Check in Date | Chec out Date | 
    ---------------------------------------
    |     |              |                |
    |     |              |                |
-------------------------------------------
```

I want the report to be in format presented by the table below.

```html
    _______________________________________

    |Name | Check in Date | Chec out Date | 
    ---------------------------------------
    |     |              |                |
    |     |              |                |
    _______________________________________

   | Total  for Day 1  |                  |
   ---------------------------------------   
    |     |              |                |
    |     |              |                |
    _______________________________________
   | Total  for Day 2  |                  |
   ---------------------------------------
```

when I run the sql query below

```html
SELECT check_in_time , chec_out_time , COUNT(check_in_time) FROM 
table_name GROUP BY check_in_time ORDER BY check_in_time DESC
```

Then I get the following result.

```html
        _______________________________________________________________
   
        |Name | Check in Date | Chec out Date | COUNT(check in time)   |
        --------------------------------------------------------------
        |     |              |                |
        |     |              |                |    2                   |
        ________________________________________________________________

        |     |              |                |
        |     |              |                |       5                 |
        ________________________________________________________________

        |     |              |                |
        |     |              |                |            3          |
        ________________________________________________________________
```

I actually want each transaction presented in their rows and the total transactions for a day in a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I use the mysql key word ROLLUP to get the desired results. Below is the sql script.

```js
SELECT check_in_time , chec_out_time , COUNT(check_in_time) FROM 
table_name GROUP BY check_in_time DESC , id WITH ROLLUP;
```